# Creating a page

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem on creating a page, i'm new at these stuffs and i'm trying to learn from my mistakes and superior's help like you,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqTcz.png <- image

As you can see, my heading is not on really top of the page, 
IT WERE right before i changed my codes for my "page".
i wanted to createa white 65% width page on the center for my text and pictures etc.. and i can't create it, don't know why, check my codes pls

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="fotos/evergreen.png" id="evergreenIMG" />
            <div>
                <img src="fotos/header.jpg" id="headerIMG" />
                <img src="fotos/evergreen.png" id="evergreenIMG" />
                <img src="fotos/off.png" id="offIMG" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pagina"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Tudo em header */
#header {
    z-index: 1;
    }

#offIMG {
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 3%;
    margin-left: 11%;
}

#headerIMG {
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    max-height: 60px;
    min-height: 60px;
    width: 80%;
}

#evergreenIMG {
    margin-left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 45%;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

/* agora é a pagina*/
#pagina {
    position: absolute
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 81px;
    margin-left: 17,5%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

body {
    background-image:url("fotos/background.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height: 100%;
}
```

i wanted to do something like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx37i.jpg
And i still don't know how, this image was edited by me on Photoshop right now, how can i do that white thing?

Comment: If it was working before you made changes, and it is not working after you made the changes, you should probably identify what the changes were.

Comment: Remove margin top from pagina http://jsfiddle.net/P3rcL/

Comment: i wanted to do something like that http://i.imgur.com/twZnSjk.jpg
And i still don't know how, this image was edited by me on Photoshop right now, how can i do that white thing?

Answer (score 0):

HTML by default comes with some unnecessary styling which just causes issues. In this case my best guess is that the issue is the HTML defaults.
Try this:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/master_stylesht.htm

Specifically the part that says to remove the margins:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
```

Also noticed on #evergreenIMG:

```
padding-top: 10px;
```

EDIT: I got the header done:
http://jsfiddle.net/yE9b9/

Comment: Look at the image OP has

Comment: i used padding-top: 10px; to put it on the middle, is it wrong?
and i used that code from html, body, but can't to the white page to put my paragrafs, you know? a 65% , height: 100% on the center in front of the background

Comment: @Huangism I did. And you're adding space to the top, try changing it. And didn't you want for it to be in the top?

Comment: i wanted to do something like that http://i.imgur.com/twZnSjk.jpg
And i still don't know how, this image was edited by me on Photoshop right now, how can i do that white thing?

Comment: Just put a white background on it, 65% width and set the height to where you desire.